# VB Net - Pass data from Thread to Main GUI

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I've managed to get the data I want in a thread, however I'm having trouble getting my head around passing the data back into my main thread (GUI).

I'm grabbing data from a network stream in a thread, then need to pass it to my main thread in order to pass to other classes etc.

I've seen it mentioned to use backgroundworker for this, but as I'm expecting it to gather data periodically and never stop, I thought a separate thread for this would be best, but I'm very new to multithreading.

If threading is the correct way to go, how can I pass data from it back to my main thread in order to use this for other stuff? I've seen delegates and events mentioned a lot but can't see how I'd pass data with these?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using an `Async` method that `Await`s the network in an infinite loop on the UI thread instead.

Comment: Thanks - Can I pass data with a custom event from a class?

Comment: No evets trigger on the same thread.

Comment: Unless you need to access the UI why do you need to pass it back to the main thread? Just do an processing on the thread.

Comment: Basically it'll be producing strings every few seconds, which I wanted to put into a listbox on the main UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please study this example, and let me know if it fits your requirements:

[image]

**Controls required:** lstItems (ListBox), btnStart (Button), btnStop (Button), Timer1 (Timer).

**Form1 code:**

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim p_oStringProducer As StringProducer

  Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    p_oStringProducer = New StringProducer
    p_oStringProducer.Start()
    Timer1.Enabled = True
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _ 
                                                          Handles btnStop.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    p_oStringProducer.Stop()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim asQueue As Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue(Of String) =
      p_oStringProducer.MessageQueue
    While asQueue.Count > 0
      Dim sItem As String = Nothing
      asQueue.TryDequeue(sItem)
      lstItems.Items.Add(sItem)
    End While
  End Sub
End Class
```

**StringProducer code:**

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class StringProducer
  Private p_fKeepRunning As Boolean
  Private p_oTask As task
  Private p_aMessageQueue As Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue(Of String)
  Private p_iNextMessageId As Integer

  Public ReadOnly Property MessageQueue As _
                             Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue(Of String)
    Get
      Return p_aMessageQueue
    End Get
  End Property

  Sub New()
    p_oTask = New Task(AddressOf TaskBody)
    p_aMessageQueue = New Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue(Of String)
    p_iNextMessageId = 0
  End Sub

  Public Sub Start()
    p_fKeepRunning = True
    p_oTask.Start()
  End Sub

  Public Sub [Stop]()
    p_fKeepRunning = False
  End Sub

  Private Sub TaskBody()
    While p_fKeepRunning
      Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
      p_aMessageQueue.Enqueue("Message #" & p_iNextMessageId)
      p_iNextMessageId += 1
    End While
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    MyBase.Finalize()
    Me.Stop()
  End Sub
End Class
```

This was not extensively tested, but it should give you a head start.

Comment: Just had a quick go with it... Looks good. If I understand, it adds the strings to a queue in order for the main thread to take them individually as and when it's ready to? Thanks a lot for your help, very useful!!!!

Comment: @JohnathonMihalop: Yep, you got it. You can further improve it to dump old messages, if not consumed by main, to prevent memory overflow. Please don't forget to accept/upvote.